What is the order of $p_{1}^{x} \bmod{n}$ where $p_1$ is a prime factor of $n$
I am looking for a formula, algorithm, or even literature on the topic.
Take $21$ for example
$21 = 7 \cdot 3$
What is the order of $3^{x} \bmod 21$?
$3^0 = 1$ 
$3^1 = 3$
$3^2 = 9$
$3^3 = 6$
$3^4 = 18$ 
$3^5 = 12 $
$3^6 = 15$
$3^7 = 3$ 
Therefore the order of $3^x \mod 21$ is $6 (3,9,6,18,12,15)$
Is there a formula or algorithm for solving order$(p,n)$?

Something is way off. Multiplicative order of an integer $a$ (or a residue class) modulo $n$ is defined only when $\gcd(a,n)=1$.

To find the order of $p$ in the modul $n$, they need to be coprime. Here there are not coprime. But as $\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ we get that it repeats after $\varphi(7)=6$.

Thats the only answer I can find is that they need to be coprime but here we have a group and I want to find its order its clearly well defined with the set I gave 3,9,6... so the fact that multiplicative order is only defined for sets that include 1 is a bit puzzling for me but never the less I am looking to see if there is literature on this topic

@calculatormathematical yes in this instance its $phi(7) =6$ but its not always the case. So what is the general formula?

Please use MathJax. Here is a
tutorial. "but here we have a group - no, we don't. We have $3\cdot 7=0$ here modulo $23$, this is a contradiction, because then in a group it would follow that $7=3^{-1}\cdot 3\cdot 7=0$, which is false modulo $23$. Because $7\neq 0$.

@calculatormathematical okay but here is an example where that doesn't hold: $n=65 = 5*13$    p1=5 order of 5 is 4 (5,25,60,40) where as phi(13)=12

Then its always one of the two -1. (?)

Well its not that either here is another example n =155 = 31 * 5 order of 5 = 3 (5,25,125) and phi of 31 is 30 so it doesn't add up

@JyrkiLahtonen what do you mean something is way off?

Usually "order" is reserved for the case when the orbit is purely cyclic, i.e. no preperiodic part. That is what is causing some confusion above.

Hint: $\!\bmod n\, $ suppose $p^{\Bbb N}$ has preperiod $j$ and period $k,\,$ i.e. $j,k$ are minimal such that $\,p^{j+k}\equiv p^j.\,$ Then $\,n\mid p^j(p^k-1)\,$ so $\,p^j\mid\mid n\,$ and $\,k\,$ is the order of $p$ modulo $n/p^j,\,$ e.g. in your example the preperiod has length $\, j= 1\,$ and the period has length $\,k = 6 = {\rm ord}_7(3)$.
Generally there is no formula for computing the order. See here for algorithms.

What you call the "order of $p$ modulo $pn$" will be a divisor of $\varphi(n)$. There is no "formula" that will tell you which divisor it is.

Thank you for your answer. Does it have a proper name other than to say the order of the group as I am aware its not the multiplicative order due to missing 1 (which doesn't make sense to me for the definition to be limited to that). Are you sure there is no formula more specific than a divisor of  $phi(n/p)$? Do you have any literature on this topic papers books?

I know of no name for this. It's not the "order" of anything. That the definition "makes no sense to you" may be because you are new to number theory - mathematicians have agreed on the actual definition because it's useful. If you had a formula for the question you ask  you would have a formula for the actual order of elements of the group $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ - a known hard problem. There will be theorems in any book on elementary number theory that address these questions.

Interesting, I am mainly asking to see if there is specific information in this regard that is already know as I couldn't find much on this yet (specifically order of numbers that are not coprime). I think the multiplicative order definition should be extended to include the orders of non coprime and there is a very good structure for them. I think its best to write this up formally for it to make any sense. Unfortunately, I don't think the formula for these solves the order in group zp :(
